# Removing Done Button from login with facebook safari view

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, button, authentication

How to remove the done button from the Facebook login safari view controller. [image]

Answer (score 0):

the done button is part of the [`SFSafariViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/) and can not be removed.